# BeautifulSoup get title returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'am using `BeautifulSoup` to parse through html and trying to retrieve a title.

My code as follows:

```
callerid = cell_list[0]
print callerid.find('a')
```

which returns the appropriate anchor tag where I'm trying to extract my "title" from.

```
<a class="caller_ref" href="/tomasi/cardio/vgh/SPsdeGBHH" 
title="CDS1255S56d">identifier</a>
```

Now here is where it gets funky. As soon as I add ["title"] to my print statement to extract the title,

```
callerid = cell_list[0]
print callerid.find('a')["title"]
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

How can this be "NoneType" when it clearly contains the anchor tag html as shown in the first example and how can I parse it to return the title?

Comment: Could you add `print callerid` after `callerid = cell_list[0]` and show result?

Comment: The addition of `["title"]` is not causing this error. The error is occurring because `callerid` is `None`.

Comment: @kvorobiev yes sure the result is
`<td class="acenter ">
<a class="caller_ref" href="/tomasi/cardio/vgh/SPsdeGBHH" 
title="CDS1255S56d">identifier</a>`
</td>

Comment: @kindall how can callerid be none seeing as when i print it alone without the ["title"] it returns the anchor tag im looking for?

Comment: Because the error message says it's `None`. How it got that way, I cannot say. Always believe the error message.

Comment: @kindall i gotta admit you were right (see answer i posted below). Words to live by  "Always believe the error message" Thnx

Answer (score 0):

`callerid.find('a')` should be `callerid.find('a').a['title']`.
It may look like it, but `callerid.find('a')` does not actually return the contents of the tag! (In fact [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) is not terribly informative as to what it **does** return...?)

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '<a class="caller_ref" href="/tomasi/cardio/vgh/SPsdeGBHH" 
title="CDS1255S56d">identifier</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
anchor = soup.find_all('a')[0]
print "title : " + (anchor.get('title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I caught the mistake, i was basically parsing through a table with multiple rows, all rows had anchor tags as such `print callerid.find('a')` would work.

But as for `print callerid.find('a')["title"]` this line would return NoneType because the first row of the table i was parsing was the only row (out of 19456 rows) to not have a title tag, which halted all further execution.

Thank you all for your help.